# Set Limit on File Size Across Entire System

Tags: files, filesystems, ulimit

I am trying to set the limit on files to be 10GB across the entire system. When `ulimit -f` is run, I get back `unlimited.`

When `ulimit -a` is run, I see that the units of file size are `blocks`. How do these convert to bytes?

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, by default 1024 bytes, but 512 bytes in POSIX mode ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins)):

> If no option is given, then `-f` is assumed. Values are in 1024-byte increments, except *[some others]* and, when in POSIX Mode (see Bash POSIX Mode), `-c` and `-f`, which are in 512-byte increments.

(POSIX, of course, [demands 512 byte blocks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ulimit.html).)

```
$ bash -c 'ulimit -Sf 1000; 
    head -c1024000 < /dev/zero > /tmp/test && echo ok;
    echo x >> /tmp/test && echo ok'
ok
File size limit exceeded
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check `/proc/partitions` to see number of blocks in a given partition and use `lsblk` or `df` to check the size of the partition in bytes. The number of bytes devided by blocks will give the bytesize of a block.

For example, on my desktop:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  312571224 sda
   8        1  308392960 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5    4175872 sda5
  11        0      19930 sr0
   8       16  244198584 sdb
km0@mkdisplay:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 294.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
sr0     11:0    1  19.5M  0 rom
$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 22 2017, 00:47:24)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 298.1*1024*1024*1024/312571224.
1024.03040701661
```

Comment: that doesn't have anything to do with what `ulimit` considers a block